# Which SE site should I ask questions on drug discovery and development?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which SE site should I ask questions on drug discovery and development? For example, I'd like to ask:

> When developing combination drugs, is it a viable
> strategy to use two drugs where drug A is a ligand to a target
> receptor and drug B is a molecule that can up-regulate the expression
> and translocation of the receptor?

> Under what circumstances is it a good idea to develop combination
> drugs, or to develop drugs that meant to be used in combination / in
> synergy with others?

Comment: If those questions qualify as *pharmacology" then they might be on topic on [Medical Science](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but I'm not a regular  on that site so do read the help and ask on their meta first.

Comment: Check out the complete sites list at https://stackexchange.com/sites. You might also try the Global search on top of that page to search across the network. If you have problems, [edit] your question to include an example or draft a question using **real** terms instead of placeholders like drug A / drug B. If you are new to health sciences, you might start at the site suggested in the previous comment. You might also start at [chemistry.se].